# Extract the count from a file linux

Tags: linux

I have a text file like this

```
22  16050213    0|0:403 1|0:1
22  16050607    0|0:400 0|1:2   1|0:2
22  16050739    0|0:403 1|0:1
22  16050783    0|0:404
22  16050840    0|0:391 0|1:9   1|0:4
22  16050847    0|0:402 1|0:2
22  16050922    0|0:404
22  16050984    0|0:404
22  16051075    0|0:404
```

`0|0:403` means the number of occurrence of `0|0` is `403` , `1|0:1` means the number of occurrence `1|0` is `1`  and so on. I want to remove the "0|0" ,etc and only have the count and fill the blanks with 0 like this :

[image: Screen Shot]

Please help me how do I do this in linux

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Perl one liner

```
/tmp> cat adhira.txt
22 16050213 0|0:403 1|0:1
22 16050607 0|0:400 0|1:2 1|0:2
22 16050739 0|0:403 1|0:1
22 16050783 0|0:404
22 16050840 0|0:391 0|1:9 1|0:4
22 16050847 0|0:402 1|0:2
22 16050922 0|0:404
22 16050984 0|0:404
22 16051075 0|0:404
/tmp> perl -ne ' s/\d+\|\d+://g; print '  adhira.txt
22 16050213 403 1
22 16050607 400 2 2
22 16050739 403 1
22 16050783 404
22 16050840 391 9 4
22 16050847 402 2
22 16050922 404
22 16050984 404
22 16051075 404
/tmp>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following sed

```
sed -E "s/([0-9]\|[0-9]:)//g" myfile
```

- `-E` enables extended regular expressions (needed for grouping)
- `"s/a/b/g"` replaces a with b
- `([0-9]\|[0-9]:)` regex matches any digit + escaped `|` + any digit + `:`

if you have numbers more than 9 in 0|0 structure you could reuse some of regex from [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

Comment: Nit, `cat file | sed ...` is a **UUOc** (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`). Unless you are actually *concatenating* two files, then `cat ...` is probably wrong. Here simply `sed ... myfile` is all you need.